# How to Decode Json object in laravel and apply foreach loop on that in laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

i am getting this request.

```
 { "area": [
        {
            "area": "kothrud"
        },
        {
            "area": "katraj"
        }
    ]
}
```

and i want to provide response to this by searching records in database based on above request. how will i decode above  json array and use each area field separately.

Comment: Please post your work on it.

Comment: your json is invalid

Answer (score 39, accepted):

your string is NOT a valid json to start with.

a valid json will be,

```
{
    "area": [
        {
            "area": "kothrud"
        },
        {
            "area": "katraj"
        }
    ]
}
```

if you do a `json_decode`, it will yield,

```
stdClass Object
(
    [area] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [area] => kothrud
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [area] => katraj
                )

        )

)
```

**Update:** to use

```
$string = '

{
    "area": [
        {
            "area": "kothrud"
        },
        {
            "area": "katraj"
        }
    ]
}

';
            $area = json_decode($string, true);

            foreach($area['area'] as $i => $v)
            {
                echo $v['area'].'<br/>';
            }
```

**Output:**

```
kothrud
katraj
```

**Update #2:**

for that `true`:

> When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays. for more information, [**click here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: i don't know how to get that json array in variable.i am sending that area array from postman rest client to webservice.i don't know how to get that array in variable and use it.

Comment: can you tell me what is ($string,true)

Comment: if that json $string array is in different view then how to bring it in controller's particular function in laravel.

Answer (score 10):

you can use `json_decode` function

```
foreach (json_decode($response) as $area)
{
 print_r($area); // this is your area from json response
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://ideone.com/lnOoL1)

Comment: but how area array will Come into json $response. I am using Postman rest client for web services and from there only i am getting array area. but i do not know how to access it in my code.

Comment: i tried but it is giving me Undefined variable: response error

Comment: are you using `curl` to get data from web service in your php code ?

Comment: @ParagBhingre post what you are trying

Comment: if that json $string array is in different view then how to bring it in controller's particular function in laravel. your suggestion is correct.But my $json is coming from web services so i dont know how to bring that $json in controller's particular function. In core php it is perfectly working